# Assembly language x86 IRVINE infinite loops

Tags: loops, assembly, x86, irvine32

I'm new to Assembly language and I need help with an error I keep experiencing, my task in class is to do what I did below, everything I did is correct and how the professor wants it but I can't stop the program from infinite looping, I have the correct answer which is 14 but how do I stop the loop from being infinite without using special commands like `ret`. How do I stop it?

```
;Declare an array of words
;Write a loop that adds all the elements of the array located in even places
;Example 3,7,2,8,9
;3+2+9=14

INCLUDE Irvine32.inc

.data

val1 WORD 3,7,2,8,9

.code

main PROC

mov eax, 0

L1:

mov ecx, (LENGTHOF val1)*(TYPE val1+2)-(TYPE val1+4)
mov eax, ecx

call writeDec

loop L1


    exit
main ENDP
END main
```

Comment: Use a debugger to single-step through your loop and you will see the problem easily.

Comment: I don't see the problem.

Comment: Watch the value of `ecx` as you single-step.  Remember that `loop` only stops looping when `ecx` reaches zero.

Comment: Okay so what will I have to do the `ecx` to make it reach 0, I'm a beginner, you're talking in another language to me.

Comment: Obviously don't re-initialize `ecx` inside the loop.  Each asm instruction makes a specific change to the state of the machine.  Find a series of steps that will produce the result you want.  That's all there is to asm programming.  (Well, that and finding the most efficient sequence of instructions to do things.)

Comment: can you show me a step by step please? I'm just not getting it. Should I replace ecx with eax?

Comment: No, your loop is nowhere near accomplishing the task.  There aren't any `add` instructions in it, or array indexing.  Ask your professor, read your textbook, or look for examples of working functions and step through them to see how they work.  (either mentally or with a debugger that shows you which registers changed from the last instruction).

Comment: I think you need to reread the earlier chapters in your textbook, or revisit the earlier exercises in this class. Your questions show that you are missing some of the basic knowledge that you need for this assignment to make sense.

Answer (score 1):

At the bottom of your  loop, you have this instruction:

`loop L1`

which means "go back to L1."

> Loop L1 is a conditional LOOP that is based on the value in ECX. The
>   real issue is the problem with the value in ECX. LOOP will first
>   decrement ECX by 1 and compare the new value in ECX with zero. If it
>   isn't zero it goes to the label (L1). If it is zero it falls through.

Look carefully at where you set the value of ecx. After LOOP decrements ecx by 1 and execution goes to L1, what happens?

Comment: `Loop L1` is a conditional [LOOP](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_161.html) that is based on the value in _ECX_. The real issue is the problem with the value in _ECX_. _LOOP_ will first decrement _ECX_ by 1 and compare the new value in _ECX_ with zero. If it isn't zero it goes to the label (_L1_). If it is zero it falls through.

Comment: @MichaelPetch  Aack, I forgot it works like that (been looking at PPC too long). I'll fix my answer to reflect your comment.

Comment: So what will I have to do? I'm still lost.

Comment: @Crashworks I move eax to ecx? Is that the problem? I don't understand. It's an infinite loop to answer your question..

Comment: loop loops CX times  (by decrementing CX by 1 and jumping to label if CX != 0). if you jump to the instruction where you set CX, you always reset your jump "counter" to the initial value, and the loop is always restarted. jump to AFTER the "mov cx, ..."